# ATS will be mantaory in IOS apps. What about simple feeds?

Tags: ios, https

As we heard this year's WWDC, a*t the end of 2016, Apple will make ATS mandatory for all developers who hope to submit their apps to the App Store.* http://9to5mac.com/2016/06/15/ats-https-ios-apps/
http://www.cso.com.au/article/577197/apple-tells-ios-9-developers-use-https-exclusively/

It is understandable in cases where privacy, encryption (...) is a factor. But what about simple (news...) feeds, API-s whare it is not the case?

What about simple json or rss feeds? E.g. I have a very simple public json feed that can be called without any authorization, will it also need https? And what about simple RSS feeds? Huge majority of them communicates now via http. What about downloading image files from the web in an app?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it not the case? Because the news you search for and browse is a form of user information...

Comment: It is not intended to improve the security of user information only, but to improve the security of the entire ecosystem. So yeah, even for simple feed it will be mandatory.

Comment: It will be definetly death of several services and apps

Comment: Why will ATS be "definetly death of several services and apps"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very rapidly becoming "the new normal."  (Did you notice that even WikiPedia now uses https connections to their site?)  Non-encrypted communications can be effortlessly intercepted, *e.g.* in the coffee shops and public places where so many people routinely find themselves.  The problem is even more severe now that "free public WiFi" is available in "ordinary" stores and Wal-Marts, *and* people have their phones set to automatically connect to any of them.  (People do not realize how *in*secure they are!  But, they're learning ...)

The most appropriate solution, then, is to "encrypt *everything."*  And so, this is what Apple is now mandating.

Yes, even "routine" communications, news-feeds and such. *All of* the traffic that passes through the airwaves will be encrypted.

Remember, also, that these techniques not only *secure* the communication, but are capable of *identifying* the sender and the receiver to one another through mutually-held certificates.  (Web sites don't always use client-identification, although they can, and *apps* definitely should.)  This, if used properly, will close a very big headache-hole for *servers,* because they now will know just who they are talking to.  Client software can trust that they *are* talking to the right server, and that their communications are "received as tendered."

"Android or iOS or Windows or what-have-you," you *should* be doing this. Every mobile device implements SSL and possibly other encryption stacks. Do not send *anything* over air-waves "in the clear."

Answer (score 0):

A "simple feed", in some country, can kill you. Protect your users, encrypt everything.